# How to access javascript value in a4j

Tags: javascript, jsf, seam, ajax4jsf

I need to set a Bean value with one javascript return value.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getUserId(){
     return 4;
  }
</script>

<h:inputText name="lala" value="getUserId()"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I was using a:jsFunction tag as it follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function getUserId(){
                var user = MyCompany.get_User();
            return user;
        }
    </script>

<a:jsFunction action="#{user.performLogin()}" name="doSiteLogin"  >
   <a:actionparam name="uid" value="getUserId()"/>
</a:jsFunction>
```

If you use the property  noEscape="true" on the a:actionparam ... it call your javascript code.